# How to save and merge RDD data in scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I want to merge existing data in hdfs with new comings from RDD. (Not by filename instead by real data inside them)

I found out there is no way to control output files' names in rdd.saveAsTextFile API, so I can not save both just by naming them with different names.

I try to merge them by Hadoop's FileUtil.copyMerge function, but I'm using Hadoop 3, which means this API is not supported ever more.

Comment: Do you want to update the files stored in HDFS?  If not then why not load them together, merge them, and save the output separately?

Comment: @PrithviSingh Thanks for reply. That's just what I did now. But once I collect too much data, would it be a large cost to load it always？